# income calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm really new to code optimization and JS. And I like to learn with clean code. I would like to ask for help on optimizing my code.

The code below parses the value of four inputs as floating point numbers and adds them together. The sum is then displayed in an output element.

```
  if(document.getElementById('salary-field').value ===''){
    salary = 0;
   }else{
    salary = parseFloat(document.getElementById('salary-field').value).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('salary-field').value = salary;
   } 
    
   if(document.getElementById('commission-field').value ===''){
    commission = 0;
   }else{
    commission = parseFloat(document.getElementById('commission-field').value).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('commission-field').value = commission;
   } 
   
   if(document.getElementById('rental-field').value ===''){
    rental = 0;
   }else{
     rental = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rental-field').value).toFixed(2);
     document.getElementById('rental-field').value = rental;
   } 
    
   if(document.getElementById('other-income-field').value ===''){
    other_income = 0;
   } else {
     other_income = parseFloat(document.getElementById('other-income-field').value).toFixed(2);
     document.getElementById('other-income-field').value = other_income;
   }
  
    sum = parseFloat(salary) + parseFloat(commission) + parseFloat(rental) + parseFloat(other_income);
    document.getElementById('sum-field').value = sum.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: @konijn - I don't remember if I had seen this relevant meta post until now: [_Do we need "acronym tags" (\[dry\], \[solid\], etc.)?_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2141/120114)

Comment: I don't know type handling in JavaScript, but the terms in the sum seem to use results of `parseFloat()` as arguments to `parseFloat()`.

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/268258/3) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

From a short review;

- You should declare your variables with `const` or `let`
- There is a ton of copy-pasted code in there
- `'commission-field'` is not a great name for your element, I would just call it `commission`
- Avoid writing multiple calls to `document.getElementById` for the same id
- Its hard to control what users enter, and sometimes `parseFloat` returns a NaN, I would always deal with that pro-actively
- I would create a function that formats an element like

  ```
  function cleanAmountElement(id){
    const elementValue = document.getElementById(id);
    const cleanerValue = parseFloat(elementValue*1).toFixed(2);
    const cleanestValue = IsNaN(cleanerValue)?0:cleanerValue;    
    document.getElementById(id).value = cleanestValue;
    return cleanestValue;
  }
  ```
- Note that this is not super super clean, that function both updates the UI and returns a value :/
- Then you can do something funky with functional programming where you pass a list of ids and process them

  ```
  const sum = ['salary', 'commission', 'rental', 'other_income'].map(cleanAmountElement)
                                                                .reduce(getSum,0);

  function getSum(a,b){
    return a+b;
  }
  ```

Comment: inputs have `valueAsNumber` which coerce empty string into `0`.

Comment: That comment is part of why I love CR ;)